# Selecting plan with FilteredElementCollector Revit Api

Tags: revit-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjbuM.png)

I am developing an application with Revit api. I'm trying to open my 3D model using FilteredElementCollector. I couldn't catch it first, I want to ask how can I do it?
I also get this error when I select another 3D model of mine.

Error : Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.InvalidOperationException: 'Setting active view is temporarily disabled.

Can you help with these issues?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By 3D model, do you mean a 3D view?

https://www.revitapidocs.com/2015/b6adb74b-39af-9213-c37b-f54db76b75a3.htm

You'll see here that changing the active view is only possible when there is no:

> There is no open transaction.
>
> IsModifiable is false.
>
> IsReadOnly is false
>
> ViewActivating, ViewActivated, and any pre-action of events (such as DocumentSaving or DocumentClosingevents) are not being handled.

Worth making sure you don't have an open transaction. If you do, and you need one you can use the RequestViewChange method:

https://www.revitapidocs.com/2015/a2e920d4-2849-282e-c25f-40a4d2cbef2d.htm

Comment: var arbitaryFloorPlan = new FilteredElementCollector(uiapp.ActiveUIDocument.Document).OfClass(typeof(View3D)).Cast<View3D>().Where(x => x.Title == "3D View: {3D}").FirstOrDefault();

UIdoc.RequestViewChange(arbitaryFloorPlan);                                                                          When I made my code like this, I was able to open a 3d view.

Comment: Great, glad to have been able to help.

Comment: Please mark the response as the answer or upvote so that others can find this as well. Thanks, and happy Revit-ing

Comment: I have a problem . I tried most of the solutions but somehow my error was not fixed. Can you help if you have any information?                                                                                              https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73136573/the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-i-get-an-error