# "The system cannot find the file specified." I get an error

Tags: c#, revit-api

I am developing a revit plugin. This plugin allows me to export my revit file as gltf but I am getting this error. When I tried other codes that did the same thing, I got the same similar error in a different nuget package. Could this have something to do with revit? How can I fix this error?

'Could not load file or assembly 'AssimpNet, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0d51b391f59f42a6' or one of its dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

In the first instance it is worth checking that the properties of the AssimpNet reference dll has its CopyLocal property set to true.